# Identifying key=value pairs in *.properties files using Java

Tags: java

We have many *.properties files in my project, and in each, we have lots and lots of key=value pairs.

The task is to find all keys that start with `_format_`
followed by any word (we can freely assume that that word will not contain any special characters nor whitespace characters) AND the value of that key IS NOT EQUAL to null (case-insensitive).

Using an example:

```
_format_Date1=null
_format_Date2=null
_format_endTerm=null
_isUpdatable_somethingA=false
_isUpdatable_somethingB=false
_format_begingTerm=null
_format_countOfMoney=\#0.00#\ -- The kind of row that must be identified with the pattern
_javaType_name1=String
_javaType_name2=String
```

We can also assume all of the key=values pairs will loaded up in a collection and read line by line.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Load the `.properties` file into an `Properties` object. Then iterate over it keys and if the `key` contains word `format` then return value of this key.

Comment: Took your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Just iterate over the files, read them in and filter line by line.

I suppose something like this could do it:

```
    Files.walk(Paths.get("path"))
         .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
         .filter(path -> path.endsWith(".properties"))
         .forEach(path -> {
                      try {
                          Files.lines(path)
                               .filter(s -> s.startsWith("_format_"))
                               .filter(s -> !s.split("=")[1].toLowerCase().equals("null"))
                               .forEach(s -> System.out.println("File " + path.toString() + " has amtching line " + s));
                      } catch (final IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
         );
```

Comment: You should use Properties class

Comment: I don't see any advantages when using the `Properties` class. Can you please tell me why it is better?

Comment: I ended up using both of your advice/suggestions. Also, note that I ended up using Properties class because it makes it clear as to what I am doing and it is straightforward to use. Whether it has any performance and/or memory advantages, I cannot say.

Comment: Furthermore, I used NIO Files to efficiently read files in, however filter that looks for at path endings did not work for me, untiI I used PathMatcher class.